# RHEL8 HTTPD php missing "apache 2.0 handler"

Tags: php

How do I install PHP on RHEL8 so that it is using "Server API" "apache 2.0 handler" instead of PHP-FPM? I believe the PHP-FPM is causing issues, and I can't see the modules enabled in apache for the web server.

I've tried installing PHP73 from "remi-php73" but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with RHEL-8, httpd work in threaded mode (event MPM) and use php-fpm for better **performance and security**.

In RHEL-8 mod_php is still provided, and it is removed in RHEL-9

mod_php is only available in old worker mode (prefork MPM), so if you switch back to it, mod_php will be used.

Check /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf to select the proper MPM

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

Also check /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php.conf to enable mod_php

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
```

> I believe the PHP-FPM is causing issues

I recommend you investigate these issues rather than trying to workaround them switching to old deprecated way.